# Is it possible to mock or overload a direct reference to Boost::Filesystem(.hpp)?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking

I'm attempting to help design some unit tests around controllers in a Qt C++ application.

To be frank, I have two large drawbacks.  One, my testing background is heavily based on .NET projects, so my knowledge of best practice in the c++ world is slim at best.  Two, the designer of the application I am looking at did not architect the code with unit testing in mind.

One specific point point, I'm looking at a controller class that includes boost/filesystem/operations.hpp.  The controller constructor goes on to check directory existence and create directories using functions from the boost filesystem code.

Is there any way to overload or mock this behavior?  I'm used to setting up an IoC container or at least dependency injected constructors in .NET, and then being able to pass mock objects in the unit test code.  I'm not sure how a templated header file would work with that concept, though, or if it is even typical practice in c++.

Currently, I have no flexibility to suggest code changes, as there is a release build coming up this week.  But after that, if there are some simple code changes that could improve testability, that is definitely an option.  Ideally, there would be a way to overload the filesystem functions in the unit test framework as is, though.

Comment: I'm struggling to believe that any piece of code that accesses the file system at run time must have this same dependency during unit testing.  I think we will probably do some re-architecting in our next release.  One option is to create wrappers around boost::filesystem and our other dependencies that I would like to mock.  I would then dependency inject the real wrapper at run time and mocked versions during unit testing.  Are there other options I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up creating a generic file system wrapper that calls Boost filesystem and accepting it as a parameter to our class constructors so we could send in mock versions at unit test time.

I understand the thought to not mock this, but I think there is value in fast unit tests for our CI environment to run at check in time as well as tests that actually hit the file system.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, the only reason why you need to inject an instance of, suppose, IFilesystem into your classes, is to mock it in tests. No part of your non-test codebase gonna use anything but the real filesystem anyway, so it is safe to assume that you can **inject** not an object but **a type** into your classes and use them freely within your codebase without type clashes.

So, suppose you have class of interest

```cpp
struct BuildTree
{
    BuildTree(std::string_view dirname) { /*...*/ }

    bool has_changed()
    {
        // iterates through files in directory
        // recurs into directories
        // checks the modification date against lastModified_
        // uses boost::filesystem::last_write_time(), etc.
    }

private:
    boost::filesystem::file_time_type lastModified_;
};
```

Now, you could inject a *type* into the class. This type will be a class with a bunch of static methods. There will be a `RealFilesystem` type that will redirect to the boost::filesystem methods, and there will be a `SpyFilesystem`.

```cpp
template <class Filesystem>
struct BuildTree
{
    // ...
    bool has_changed()
    {
        // uses Filesystem::last_write_time(), etc.
    }

private:
    typename Filesystem::file_time_type lastModified_;
};
```

The `SpyFilesystem` will resemble a PIMPL idiom, in that the static methods will redirect calls to the actual implementation.

```cpp
struct SpyFilesystemImpl;

struct SpyFilesystem
{
    using file_time_type = typename SpyFilesystemImpl::file_time_type;

    static file_time_type last_time_write(std::string_view filename)
    {
        return instance.last_time_write(filename);
    }
    
    // ... more methods

    static SpyFilesystemImpl instance;
};

SpyFilesystemImpl SpyFilesystem::instance{};

// No warranty of completeness provided
struct SpyFilesystemImpl
{
    using file_time_type = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;

    void create_directory(std::string_view path) { /*...*/ }
    void touch(std::string_view filename)
    {
        ++lastModified_[filename];
    }
    
    file_time_type last_time_write(std::string_view filename)
    {
        return std::chrono::system_clock::time_point{lastModified_[filename]};
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::chrono::seconds> lastModified_;
};
```

Finally, inside each of your tests you would prepare an instance of `SpyFilesystemImpl`, assign it to the `SpyFilesystem::instance` and then instantiate your class with `SpyFilesystem`. like so

```cpp
// ... our SpyFilesystem and friends ...

// Google Test framework
TEST(BuildTree, PickUpChanges)
{
    SpyFilesystemImpl fs{};
    fs.create_directory("foo");
    fs.touch("foo/bar.txt");

    SpyFilesystem::instance = fs;

    BuildTree<SpyFilesystem> tree("foo");
    EXPECT_FALSE(tree.has_changed());

    SpyFilesystem::instance.touch("foo/bar.txt");
    EXPECT_TRUE(tree.has_changed());
}
```

This approach has an advantage that there will be no run-time overhead in the resulting binary (provided that optimizations are enabled). However, it requires more boilerplate code, which might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems reasonable to me to consider `boost::filesystem` as an
extension of the standard libraries.  So you mock it (or not) in
exactly the same way you mock something like `std::istream`.
(Generally, of course, you don't mock it, but rather your test
framework provides the necessary environment: the files you need
to read with `std::istream`, the directories, etc. for
`boost::filesystem`.)

Comment: Are you suggesting there is a standard (or at least viable) way to mock or overload those functions?  I'm not familiar with a way, and the method to make that happen is exactly what I am looking for.  For example, I don't want to create target directories in my unit test, I want to have a method that confirms the create directories function was called with expected values.

Comment: One more note on this, I have no problem (maybe even some interest) in incorporating a mocking framework like Google Mock.  The code base is already setup to use google test.  I'm just not clear on whether this will help with a direct template header reference.

Comment: @Evan Actually, I'm suggesting that you don't mock them at all; that you link and use them as they are.  This may mean some additional work when setting up your tests, but I suspect that it's the simplest and most reasonable solution.

Comment: One of the important rules of writing a good unit test is to not do I/O tasks. So do not depend on reading or writing from disk. Unit tests should run fast and reliable. Runs in memory. And unit tests should run in isolation.